# Is there a way to wrap a interface inside a object with a name like "extension"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have two Objects, that have a lot of variable names in common. Is there a way to wrap some of the variables inside a object with a prefix like extension?
The code snippet below work, and I can retrieve the variable from themeB. The problem is that typescript throws the Error:

> Property 'extension' does not exist on type 'ThemeType'.ts(2339)

```
theme = { ...themeA, extension: { ...themeB }};
```

Comment: From the javascript perspective, everything is okay. Could you provide typescript types for that?

Comment: I think I have to many types for that.
To clarify, Both themes implement an interface. the interface of themeB extends the interface of ThemeA. The problem is interface does not have the type extension.

Comment: Just create a new type for that (extend theme ar just create alias: `ThemeType & { extension: ThemeType }`). Or define a new inline variable and you won't need to specify the type (typescript will create the type automatically).